# Want to show DocuSign in Angular in iframe

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, docusignapi

New Image..

[image]

I want to use Docusign so user can sign Pdf using that.

I want to set that in iFrame.

I am using .net core in backend and Angular in front end.

So flow will be like in Angular user will click on button and it will check if user is login in their docusign Account or not.

If not then login page will be displayed and after that PDF will be displayed and user can sign that.

This all will be done through iframe.

I have studied few code but I am confused like where to start.. Because I downloaded sample code and run it but that code run as MVC web app.

Now I need to make in in Angular iframe.. so if any one can help me to get started this at some point then  I can take further..

Like how should I start this if anyone has any idea on this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the MVC app working, you're 80% of the way to a solution.
What you need to do is replace the front-end with your Angular webpage.
The code that does all the back-end work to make the API calls is isolated in the project you downloaded from quickstart in the file **EmbeddedSigningCeremony.cs** That is the main logic.
It will then generate a URL for you, you can use this URL as the location of your Angular iframe.
There are a few other pieces of code you need from the project to get it working which include the following files:
Session.cs, User.cs, DSConfiguration.cs, RequestItemService.cs and IRequestItemService.cs

Comment: Thanks for reply.. my confusion is when I am running this app and if I am not logged in Docusign then this class not calling at all.. and it is redirecting to this URL `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth` -- so In angular how can I get this url if user is not logged in..

Comment: Do you want your user to log in or you don't want to?

Comment: Can you please give me solution idea for both like user log in and also don't log in

Comment: User log in - you use Auth Code Grant option for C# Quickstart
User doesn't log in - you use JWT option for C# Quickstart

Comment: @Gazit I have successfully make it working using JWT.. Now I want to display in iframe in angular.. I am returning this kind of URL `https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/GUID?slt=eyJ..` And trying to show this URL in iframe but in iframe it is not showing this.. Any thought on this

Comment: Are you getting an error? can you check F12 developer tools?

Comment: error is not coming.. but I come to know that I need to add origin url.. but it's my localhost url and docusign admin side is not allowing me to add localhost url in origin url.. any solution for that

Comment: Put the code on codepen.io maybe?

Comment: Or you can use ngrok

Comment: That's not possible.. it's web app for company and I can't do that

Comment: any other possibilities for not showing page in iframe. do I need to set any options or anything

Comment: You can redirect instead of showing in an iframe

Comment: Client requirements is to show in iframe..

Comment: is client requirement to use localhost?

Comment: Iframe issue is solved..  Now I want to add Sign here field in existing PDF.. so is there any way to do that..

Comment: yes, of course, in your code that makes the envelope you can add it inside the recipient object

Comment: If you post your code - I can show you

Comment: I am getting this error, I have edited question and added image in that.. Any idea on this.. Thanks

Comment: What is the API call you're making when you get this error?